# "Project not added to Subversion because it is out of working copy"

Tags: svn, visualsvn

I'm trying to add project to svn and got such error:

Warning: Project 'C:\myproj.csproj' not added to Subversion because it is out of working copy. Please setup working copy root using VisualSVN -> Set Working Copy Root menu.

What should I do? What should be set as Working Copy Root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the working copy root to a folder where your checked out working copies resides. Like `c:\svnwork\`. Then you move `C:\myproj.csproj` to that working copy.

I'm pretty sure you don't want to check out a working copy directly in `c:\`.

To be clear, you need to have a checked out working copy and all files you want to add do that working copy needs to be in a subpath of that working copy.

Comment: thanks, moved my project to be subfolder of the working copy and this helped

Answer (score 1):

In menu Visual Studio 2015, you choice Visual SVN > Set Working Copy Root > In Working Copy Root dialog **uncheck** Determine working copy root automatically and Browse to Website folder.
[image]